# simple 3 Column responsive layout

Tags: html, css

I have a simple three column layout that I cannot seem to get working. This will probably be super easy for most of you but for some reason I cannot get it working.

```
<div>min-width</div><div>stay in center</div><div>min-width</div>
```

here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/x7Atq/

the fiddle looks like crap but basically the left / right column should size down to the min-width then start shrinking the middle down and all the containers should stay 30px margin between each other...right now when it hits min-width the second / middle container moves over the first container as the browser window is resized, I need the box to stay put, just keep getting smaller...as if the two sides were to smush in on the middle container

trying to do this with just css so no third party anything if possible, I know of things like the perfect three column layout and bootsrap but I feel like there has to be a pure css solution for this?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advice you to use the css `display: table` and `display: table-cell` wich are widely underused. Here's you working simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u5nR2/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
        <div>one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <div>two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <div>three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{height:100%;}

.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: table;
}
div > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.one {width:15%; background:#ccc}
.two {width: 60%; background:#cba}
.three {width: 25%; background:#ca8}
```

This does allow you to have *width* in `%`

Comment: I put a min-width on the .one and .three and it worked! both columns get smaller to a min-width and the middle container fills up the rest of the space respectively! I knew it was simple css. Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/u5nR2/2/

Comment: How can a constant margin be maintained using `table` and `table-cell` ?

Comment: I dont know if this is what your talking about @prtksxna , but when I started putting lots of content in and around the divs structured this way with css tables, it was next to impossible to move things around with margin or padding...I was wondering if thats what you referring to above, cause the css tables have made it nearly impossible to move objects inside without top / left which I heard isn't good to use because using relative positioning messes with the document flow. Any info appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntax issues in your CSS, for example `display:float:left;` won't do anything. Also, you can't have a fixed margin and widths defined in percentage as you wouldn't know if that much space is even left on the screen or not.

Is this the result that you wanted - http://jsfiddle.net/x7Atq/7/

Comment: sorry about that bad code...
What I want is the far left and right columns get smaller from say 10% to a min-width because they are both navigation with important information so I dont want them to get too small...So I think the left one needs to be float left and the last container should be float right so they are always on the left and right sides of the screen....then the middle just fills up what is inbetween...right now if you put float on the last container the middle doesnt fill up the space on the right http://jsfiddle.net/x7Atq/12/

Comment: Im trying to clarify better...so basically the left and right columns should always stay on screen and the middle container is just whatever space is left between them...I can then put a min-width on the overall site container so the info in the middle isnt too small, but thats the layout I need, hopefully that made a bit more sense