# dynamic / responsive / liquid layout css

Tags: css, dynamic, liquid

I was wondering if there is an alternative to writing css rather than with css tables to make liquid / dynamic layouts. vinyll really helped me here... [simple 3 Column responsive layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342077/simple-3-column-responsive-layout)

and that is exactly how I need the columns to work, but when I use css tables, it seems I cannot position things inside with margin and padding (I probably could with left and right but relative positing breaks the document flow so I don't want to do that)...heres and example
http://jsfiddle.net/u5nR2/4/

```
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
display: table;
}
div > div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.three div{margin-top:100px}/*why doesnt this move?*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use padding on the parent element. Margin needs an other element to bounce.

Change

```
.three div{margin-top:100px}
```

To

```
.three { padding-top: 100px; }
```

Also, change: `div > div` to `.container > div`. I assume you only want to select the direct child divs of `.container`. When you use `div > div`, the divs inside `.one`, `.two` and `.three` will also be selected. (also mind the `vertical-align: top` to position the text in the table-cells at the top)

Check your [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5nR2/5/)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't try putting more container divs inside each col to make margins work. and padding seems to move the table-cells..Thanks!! I was curious though if this is the best way of going about this...are css tables bad to use or are they fine?

Comment: IMHO its okay. It designed to make element *behave* like tables. It bothers me more that some try to style list or divs to show tabular data. (btw, if the answer suits you, please mark it as solution, using the "v" on the left side)